# How to search for a graphical string?

Tags: x64dbg, strings, graphics

I am trying to search for a string but in my case, that string is not like a normal string but it's a graphical string.

[image]

As you have seen, that is not a normal string that can search for but it's a string merged with a picture, I don't know what type of that control I can search for.

I am using the `x64dbg` debugger to find that string but there is no string like that.

**What way do I use to find something like that?**

Comment: A string is a string .. unless it's an image.

Comment: @MegaTonnage: Maybe it's an image I am not sure, but how do I access it?

Comment: If you can't find it as an ascii or unicode string, then I would try to locate image resources. They may be bundled into the binary so I would try a resource editor to search for it first, or it may be in an external file in which case you'll need to dig deeper.